# why is the http service being called automatically

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-services, angular-http

From the `Http service` the data is fetched and then is passed into `cached service` the compoenent subcribes to `cached service` and makes the http request when initiated.

the http get service is supposed to be called when the user clicks on an anchor tag. clicking on anchor tag navigates to the route passing the `id` and then based on the id fetching the data and displaying the view.

But when I loaded the app it broke giving following error `id = undefined`
I just started the app didnt or clicked to make these requests

```
GET https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/undefined?apikey 404 (Not Found)
GET https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/undefined?apikey 404 (Not Found)
```

// HTTP data services which fetch the data from server

```
getChar(): Observable<any> {
    const characters = this.http.get('https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters?apikey');
    const comics = this.http.get('https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/comics?apikey');
    const characterDetail = this.http.get(`${this.urlChar}${this.charId}${this.apiKey}`);
    const comicsDetail = this.http.get(`${this.urlCom}${this.comicsId}${this.apiKey}`);
    return Observable.forkJoin([characters, comics, characterDetail, comicsDetail]);
    // .map(responses => {
    //    // responses[0] => cars
    //    // responses[1] => bikes
    // });
```

// service which stores the data from server to local variables

```
getComDe(id: string): any {
    this.dt.comicsId = id;
    this.dt.getChar().subscribe((responses: Response) => {
      this.comDd = responses[3].json().data.results;
      this.comDtls = this.chDd;
      console.log(this.comDtls);
    });
```

// component subcribes to and passes the `id`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.comDl.getComDe(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
  }
```

Comment: Whats the exact issue , its kinda confusing

Comment: app is not loading correctly and giving the error mentioned above

Comment: What are these varibles this.http.get(`${this.urlChar}${this.charId}${this.apiKey}`); ?

Comment: first is url to fetch the character. second is the `id` of the character which gets passed to it when clicked. third is the api key. Id is undefined. The id is supposed to be sent to when clicked on anchor link

Comment: Where is the code of it?

Comment: <li class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let comics of comicsList">
        <a [routerLink]="['comics/', comics.id]">

Comment: the link when clicked passes the parameters. which is fetched in the component its routing to. as you can see in the last code in the question. and then that id is passed into the function. when then sets the id in the http service

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is how your code is written :

```
// template side
<li class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let comics of comicsList"> <a [routerLink]="['comics/', comics.id]">
// component side
this.comDl.getComDe(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
```

This way either you get comic_id or character_id
But you have writter code for both

```
const characterDetail = this.http.get(`${this.urlChar}${this.charId}${this.apiKey}`);
const comicsDetail = this.http.get(`${this.urlCom}${this.comicsId}${this.apiKey}`);
```

That's the reason ,

```
GET https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/undefined?apikey 404 (Not Found)
GET https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/undefined?apikey 404 (Not Found)
```

Replace your `getChar()` function with this :

```
getChar(): Observable<any> {

    var Observables = [];
    Observables.push(this.http.get('https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters?apikey'));
    Observables.push(this.http.get('https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/comics?apikey'));

    if(this.charId)
        Observables.push(this.http.get(`${this.urlChar}${this.charId}${this.apiKey}`));
    if(this.comicsId)
        Observables.push(this.http.get(`${this.urlCom}${this.comicsId}${this.apiKey}`));

    return Observable.forkJoin(Observables);
    // .map(responses => {
    //    // responses[0] => cars
    //    // responses[1] => bikes
    // });
}
```

Comment: would it work if i'd just add `if` conditional. without using the `push`

Comment: and there are two seperate function to fetch. I just showed the `getcomDe`

Comment: here it is `getCharDe(id: string): any {
    this.dt.charId = id;
    this.dt.getChar().subscribe((responses: Response) => {
      this.chDd = responses[2].json().data.results;
      this.chDtls = this.chDd;
      console.log(this.chDtls);
    });
  }`

Comment: @SONGSTER, I know , will you please put my code and run it. It will work as you expects , `getChar` function will be called each time you subscribe to this function.

Comment: can you please explain your answer in more detail

Comment: All you need to know is getChar function will be called when you subsribe to it,in that function you are getting both charcter and comic details, that should be conditional , you are calling same function but by two different methods, one will pass comic_id another will pass character_id, but in both case either charact or comic id missed, getting ?

Comment: but i called it in two different components and addint to different variable. how is that pointing to one thing

Comment: @SONGSTER, please go thorugh the function getChar and console log each varible , you will get the idea .

Comment: but when clicking on anchor link, it doesnt navigate to the component, instead routes to 404 not found

Comment: would you please consider upvoting my question as well. and if possible help me with this route problem

Comment: @SONGSTER , will you please accept the answer and also upvote it ?